# Three.js extrude 2d face whilst rotating about extrusion axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking to rotate a shape during extrusion to show a "twisting" effect about the Z-axis like here

[image]

and here

[image]

My attempt at generating this twisted cube is below:

```
var squareShape = new THREE.Shape();
squareShape.moveTo(10,0);
squareShape.lineTo(0,10);
squareShape.lineTo(-10,0);
squareShape.lineTo(0,-10);
squareShape.lineTo(10,0);


var extrudeSettings={amount:10, bevelEnabled:false};
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( gearShape, extrudeSettings );
```

Obviously this only extrudes the shape straight along the z axis. Is doesn't seem possible to shear the cube into a twist about the z axis using geometry.applyMatrix(  );

It may be that the only way to do this is to hard code something into the normals, bi-normals and tangents of the 2D shape whilst it's extruding. I believe the answer lies within extrudePath — THREE.CurvePath and frames-THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames but unsure if there is an easier method.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To achieve that 'twist' effect you most likely would have to use a separate library like [MOD3](https://github.com/foo123/MOD3). It works with Three.js and has a 'Twist' modifier.

Comment: Thanks @guardabrazo - development for MOD3 appears to have stopped. Do you know of anything that is still in active development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can twist the mesh by a certain helix angle if you know the z value at which the vertices create the face. In this case we rotate all the vertices with a z value if width/2 by a certain angle...

```
function twistMesh(mesh, helixAngle, width) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mesh.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        if (mesh.geometry.vertices[i].z == width/2.0) {
        var updateX = mesh.geometry.vertices[i].x * Math.cos(helixAngle)
                    - mesh.geometry.vertices[i].y * Math.sin(helixAngle);
        var updateY = mesh.geometry.vertices[i].y * Math.cos(helixAngle)
                    + mesh.geometry.vertices[i].x * Math.sin(helixAngle);
        mesh.geometry.vertices[i].x = updateX;
        mesh.geometry.vertices[i].y = updateY;
        }  
    }
        return mesh;
   }
```

You can also taper the mesh by...

```
function taperMesh(mesh, scaleFactor, width) {

     for (var i = 0; i < mesh.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
       if (mesh.geometry.vertices[i].z == width/2.0) {
        var updateX = mesh.geometry.vertices[i].x * scaleFactor;
        var updateY = mesh.geometry.vertices[i].y * scaleFactor;

        mesh.geometry.vertices[i].x = updateX;
        mesh.geometry.vertices[i].y = updateY;

        }  else {
           }
      }
        return mesh;
    }
```